# CopyOnWriteArrayList iteration inconsistancy with multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, iteration

I'm currently sending batches of Strings in CopyOnWrite ArrayLists with ExecutorService to be processed in parallel, where the Runnable task processing these lists need to iterate over the list and do processing on each String.

After running into issues with concurrency with regular ArrayLists, I tried to use CopyOnWriteArrayLists because they're thread-safe, however my results are now inconsistent. That is, I get different results on every run of the program, suggesting that the contents of the arraylist is changed in some way before each Runnable taks can fully iterate over it.

```
public static class BatchRunnable implements Runnable {

    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> batch;

    BatchRunnable(CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> batch){
        this.batch = batch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        //iterate over batch and work with String elements
        //make no modifications to batch
    }
}
```

- The runnable task makes NO modifications to the arraylist, it only iterates over the list and uses the String elements of the list to do processing.
- The ONLY place in which the CopyOnWriteArrayList is changed is at its instantiation with each new Runnable task.

When I was passing in single Strings instead of batching, I had consistent and correct results, but when I began to use batches in String ArrayLists, I got inconsistent results, suggesting something is compromising the concurrency of CopyOnWriteArrayList batch, despite it being supposedly thread-safe.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Here is where my batches are being constructed:

```
        Runnable worker = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            recordBatch.add(line);
            if(recordBatch.size() == 100){
                worker = new BatchRunnable(recordBatch);
                executor.execute(worker);
                recordBatch.clear();
            }

        }           
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: If you were fully constructing the batches before iterating over them (i.e. no other threads were changing things) then I'd have expected you to be okay with ArrayList anyway. This suggests that you've got something changing your batches unexpectedly. You should look into that side of things.

Comment: I added the way I'm constructing the batches, is there perhaps some reason to believe that's causing problems?

Comment: Side comment: you should use a blocking queue instead - that is exactly what they were meant to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into your `while` loop:

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        recordBatch.add(line);
        if(recordBatch.size() == 100){
            worker = new BatchRunnable(recordBatch);
            executor.execute(worker);
            recordBatch.clear();
        }

    }
```

You are passing the reference to same `list` in all the `BatchRunnable`. So, as soon as you change the `list` at one place, it will be reflected in all the reference. So, once you clear your list using `recordBatch.clear()`, the list is empty for all the references, even the one you are having in `BatchRunnable`. That is why you are getting inconsistent result.

You should pass a `copy` of your `recordBatch` list in your `BatchRunnable`:

```
worker = new BatchRunnable(new ArrayList<String>(recordBatch));
```

Comment: @howlerdingdong. Check my edit. You need to pass a copy of your list. Change your first statement in `if` to the one I posted at the end.

Comment: Success! Thank you. I didn't realise I was passing a reference that could cause issues!

Answer (score 1):

You are clearing the batch after passing it to the `BatchRunnable`.

```
 worker = new BatchRunnable(recordBatch);
 executor.execute(worker);
 recordBatch.clear(); // You clear all the list
```

So the executor will process whatever is in the list but if the clear() line is reached (and since the exeuctor runs on a different thread this might happen before the `BatchRunnable` finishes) than the list will be empty (or contain the next batch!) and the worker batch will have an inconsistent list.

When you pass the list to the worker you are passing a reference and not a copy! so either copy the batch or create a new one for each batch :

```
 worker = new BatchRunnable(recordBatch);
 executor.execute(worker);
 recordBatch = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use an iterator to go through the elements. The iterator provides a snapshot of the state of the list when the iterator was constructed. No synchronization is needed while traversing the iterator.

So in your case you should acquire the iterator in the constructor, or make a copy of the `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running into concurrency issues with plain a `ArrayList`, this shows that it is modified while your `BatchRunnable` are iterating on it.
Replacing the `ArrayList` with a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` will only hide your concurrency problems.

In your code you are modifiying (`clear()` and `add()` the list while creating the BatchRunnable. When the first runnable is submitted, it starts processing the list but you still continue modifying it.